# Abstract Algebra, Dummit and Foote, Exercises 4.3, number 5. Class Equation for Group of order 15

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question in the book is as follows:
"Assume $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $15$. Prove that $Z(G) = 1$. Use the fact that generator $g$ is a subgroup of Centraliser of $g$ for all $g$ belonging to $G$ to show that there is a most one possible class equation for $G$. [Use Excercise 36, Section 3.1".

Exercise 36 shows that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, the group is cyclic.

Well, for an order $15$ group, the subgroups are of order $15$, $5$, $3$ and $1$.
Furthermore, subgroups of order $5$ and $3$ are of prime order and thus cyclic by Cauchys theorem.

All Centralisers are of order $5$ or $3$ or $1$ as they are all groups. Centralisers cannot be of order $15$ as that would make $G$ Abelian.

All centralisers are therefore cyclic as they are groups of prime order.

Back to the main problem: if $Z(G)$ is $3$, then $G/Z(G)$ would be $5$. This would make it cylic. The same applies to $Z(G)$ being $5$. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then the group is Abelian. Therefore $Z(G)$ is $1$.

The class equation must be $15= 1 + 3\cdot A + 5\cdot B$ and must add up to $15$. The only number allowing this is $B = 1$ and $A = 3$.

**Question**
Is the statement that the generator of $g$ is a subgroup of the Centraliser of $g$ true in general or is it only true in this context ?
I dont really use this fact in my proof. Instead I use Cauchy. Why is the generator of $g$ a subgroup of the centraliser of $g$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the only group of order $15$ is, up to isomorphism, cyclic (and hence abelian).

Comment: Shaun that is true. But that is in the next section. That is, there is no way for me to show that just using the machinery that is given in the question. So one would use Sylovs rules or some such thing, which is not yet covered in the text. 

Obviously knowledge of what has been covered in the text until this question is raised cannot be expected from someone reading this question.

Comment: It's not true that "if G/Z(G) is cyclic, the group is cyclic".

Comment: Indeed, consider an abelian group $G$ that is not cyclic. We have $G=Z(G)$, so $G/Z(G)$ is trivial and hence cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

The fact $\langle g\rangle\subseteq C_G(g)$ $($and hence $\langle g\rangle\le C_G(g))$ is general, because any power of $g$ commutes with $g$ itself. What is true in your case, instead, is that $\langle g\rangle=C_G(g)$ for every noncentral (*i.e.* nontrivial) $g\in G$. You used this fact to come up the only possible class equation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $g$ centralises $g$, so $g \in C_G(g)=\{x \in G: xg=gx\}$. Hence also $\langle g \rangle \subseteq C_G(g)$, since the centraliser is a subgroup. So it is a general fact. It works here since $15$ is (relatively) small and square free. Finally, observe that (at the level of centralisers of subgroups) $C_G(g)=C_G(\langle g \rangle)$.

Answer (score -2):

Prove that $R^*$ and $M$ satisfy the two axioms in Section 1.7 for a group action of the multiplicative group $R^*$ on the set $M$.